# Вращение перевёрнутого куба (OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl

В Android NDK с помощью касаний пытаюсь научить куб вращаться.
Вращение происходит, но с одним но: если перевернуть куб на 180 градусов, например, по оси Y, то по оси X куб будет вращаться не в ту сторону - ведёшь палец справа налево, а куб поворачивается направо.
Как заставить куб понимать, что он перевернулся? Если есть примеры, то буду рад.

Comment: нужен код.

Comment: Товарищ, я не вижу кода, но по логике вещей я думаю так. Нужно постоянно знать, какая стенка куба является передней в данный момент времени. Когда крутишь куб, то функция обработки касаний должна сначала проверять, какая сторона куба спереди и уже тогда придавать вращение.

Answer (score 3):

В первую очередь необходимо понимать, что сам по себе куб не вращается(если, конечно, Вы не пересчитываете положение его вершин специально), изменяется система координат, в которой он рисуется. Система координат задаётся матрицами. Так вот, когда Вы выполняете поворот на 180 градусов вокруг Y, ось Y как раз никуда не девается, а вот X и Z отражаются, и в итоге новая система координат получается уже не "XYZ", а "-XY-Z".

Вам необходимо перевести вектор вращения(это могут быть те самые dx,dy, на которые пользователь провёл по экрану пальцем, и которые Вы, как я понял, используете в качестве углов поворота по X и Y) из системы координат экрана в систему координат объекта(то есть умножить вектор на модельно-видовую матрицу кубика), и уже потом вращать на полученные в этой системе координат углы. Как-то так.

Прошу прощения, пока без кода, но, если до завтра не разберетесь, постараюсь помочь более внятно.